# Posting data to Firebase (React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set the current state data to Firebase, however whenever I click "submit", nothing is posted. Initial state is set above the code below (not included).

Below is where I am trying to submit the data

```
   handleSubmit(evt){
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    firebase.database().ref('users/'+user.iud).set({
      title: this.state.answers.title,
      location: this.state.answers.location,
      description: this.state.answers.description
    });

  }
```

Input data gets set to state.

```
  handleChange(evt){

    const target = evt.target
    const name = target.name
    const value = target.value

    this.setState({
      answers: {
        [name]: value
      }
    })

    console.log(this.state.answers)
  }
```

What is being rendered

```
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form>

          <label>Title of Listing:</label>
          <input value={this.state.answers.title} name="title" type='text' placeholder="title" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/>

          <label>Location:</label>
          <input value={this.state.answers.location} name="location" type='text' placeholder="location" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/>
          <br />

          <label>Description:</label>
          <textarea value={this.state.answers.description} name="description" type='text'placeholder='description' onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/>

          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" onSubmit={(evt) => this.handleSubmit(evt)}/>

        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Try adding a callback to see if and error is occurring on set. `firebase.database().ref('users/'+user.iud).set({...}, function (error) { if(error) console.log(error); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there must be a typo problem here.

```
 firebase.database().ref('users/'+user.iud)
```

Try the same with

```
firebase.database().ref('users/'+user.uid)
```